# Symfony Entity id is null in Unit Test

Tags: php, doctrine, phpunit, symfony4

Hi I have a question i have a script that has this

```
public function add(Request $request): UserResponse
{
    $user = new User();

    /** @var $request UserRequest */
    $user->setName($request->getName());
    $user->setEmail($request->getEmail());

    $this->dataService->addUpdate($user);

    return new UserResponse(
        $user->getId(),
        $user->getName(),
        $user->getEmail()
    );
}
```

Now I want to Unit Test this function, but it gives me the error that `$user->getId()` is `null` instead of an `int` (the `UserResponse()` want the first parameter to be `int` and not `null`)

But of course when I make a new `User()` object in my Unit Test it has no ID in it, that is set by the EntityManager (by for me, magic)

I already tried to do something with

```
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass(get_class($user));
$idProperty = $reflectionClass->getProperty('id');
$idProperty->setAccessible(true);
$idProperty->setValue($user, 1);
```

But this will not help, anyone knows how to fix this error:

```
1) App\Tests\Service\UserServiceTest::addTest
Expectation failed for method name is equal to 'addUpdate' when invoked 1 time(s)
Parameter 0 for invocation App\Service\DataService::addUpdate(App\Entity\User Object (...)): void does not match expected value.
Failed asserting that two objects are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 App\Entity\User Object (
-    'id' => 1
+    'id' => null
     'name' => 'test'
     'identifier' => null
     'email' => 'test@test.nl'
```

Comment: Where is that ID set? IN the given code, you don't manipulate it

Answer (score 0):

The id from your Entity will only be automatically generated id if you persit and flush.

```
public function add(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em): UserResponse
{
    $user = new User();

    /** @var $request UserRequest */
    $user->setName($request->getName());
    $user->setEmail($request->getEmail());

    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();

    dd($user->getId);
}
```